# how to flag imap message /Deleted via go imap library

Tags: go, imap

I'm looking to develop Go code to read email from an IMAP server and then delete the message (i.e. flag it /Deleted and expunge). This is **not** how to do it, as it seems to be a no-op. The variable *message_id* is an uint32 message number.

```
delset, _ := imap.NewSeqSet(string(message_id))
cmd2, err = client.Store(delset, "+FLAGS", "/Deleted")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error on store command, err: %s\n", err)
    return
}
// below just stalls in a wait forever...
// Process responses while the command is running
// for cmd2.InProgress() {
//  // Wait for the next response (no timeout)
//  // client.Recv(-1)
//  // Process command data
//  for _, rsp2 = range cmd2.Data {
//      fmt.Println("Response from store")
//      fmt.Println(rsp2)
//  }
// }

// And later:
// Expunge
cmd3, err = client.Expunge(nil)
```

Comment: import (
 "code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap"
 "fmt"
 "time"
 "net/mail"
 "bytes"
 "mime"
 "mime/multipart"
 "strings"
 "io"
 "io/ioutil"
 "os"
    )

Comment: The flag is spelled \Deleted, which will make a large difference.

Answer (score 0):

I got directed to the answer found in demo code that is part of the package.

https://github.com/mxk/go-imap/blob/master/imap-demo/demo1.go#L94

Note, this package location is preferred over the code.google.com location. And, yes, the flag is \Deleted.